# How make a controller use a specific @ControllerAdvice and not another?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to have multiple implementations of `@ControllerAdvice` for different types of controllers. How do I force a controller to use only the one I want?

I can ***not*** use `@ControllerAdvice( assignableTypes = MyController.class )` because I am putting the controller advice in a jar that will be pulled in as a dependency and users will create their controllers later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a specific or list of annotations in your Jar, then in controllerAdvice you can use "annotations" declaration to control the operations. And Controllers that are annotated with this/one of those annotation(s) declared in @ControlledAdvice will be assisted by the @ControllerAdvice annotated class.

Comment: You should have posted an example